# Android: Result of TextView.setText() overridden by fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I'm a bit new to using fragments, and am having an issue with setting the text of a TextView within a fragment.

Right now, I have a single Activity with a common set of six buttons, along with two fragments which are displayed in a LinearLayout. I am able to use the buttons to replace the fragment in the LinearLayout successfully. However, I'm noticing some strange behavior related to changing a TextView in those two fragments.

I have a method in the fragments' class, called setTimer(), which attempts to change the text in the TextView. The strange thing is, the method works successfully. However, a split second later, the text reverts back to the default text in the TextView contained in the fragment's layout .xml file (which is a blank string).

I've tried calling the setTimer() method both before and after I `replace` the fragment in the LinearLayout, and the results are the same either way. How can I change this TextView's contents without having them overridden moments later? Thank you!

MainActivity.java's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FocusFragment initialFragment = new FocusFragment();
        initialFragment.setFragmentType( Constants.FRAGMENT_WORK );
        initialFragment.setTimer( 25 );
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add( R.id.linearLayout_fragmentHolder, initialFragment, "fragment_work" )
                .commit();
    }
}
```

FocusFragment.java:

```
public class FocusFragment extends Fragment {

    int fragment_type;
    static TextView timer;

    final String TAG = "FocusFragment";

    public FocusFragment() {

    }

    public void setFragmentType( int fragment_type ) {
        this.fragment_type = fragment_type;
    }

    public int getFragmentType() {
        return this.fragment_type;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        if ( getFragmentType() == Constants.FRAGMENT_WORK ) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_work, container, false );
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_break, container, false );
        }
        timer = ( TextView ) rootView.findViewById( R.id.textView_timer );
        return rootView;
    }

    public boolean setTimer( int timerValue ) {
        if ( timer != null ) {
            if ( timerValue < 10 ) {
                timer.setText( "0" + timerValue + ":00" );
            } else {
                timer.setText( timerValue + ":00" );
            }
            Log.d( TAG, "Timer text set successfully." );
            return true;
        }
        Log.w( TAG, "WARNING: setTimer() couldn't find the timer TextView!" );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, the changeFragment() method, which is called when the buttons are pressed:

```
public void changeFragment( String fragmentName, int timerValue ){
    FocusFragment fragment = new FocusFragment();
    if ( fragmentName == "fragment_work" ) {
        fragment.setFragmentType( Constants.FRAGMENT_WORK );
    } else {
        fragment.setFragmentType( Constants.FRAGMENT_BREAK );
    }
    fragment.setTimer( timerValue );
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace( R.id.linearLayout_fragmentHolder, fragment, fragmentName )
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `OnCreateView()` method of the fragment is called after the `setTimer()` is called.

An easy way to solve this is to first call `fragment.setTimerValue(value)` when you create the fragment.

```
void setTimerValue(int value){
    this.timerValue = value;
}
```

Then at the end of `OnCreateView()` method do:

```
OnCreateView(){
    ...
    setTimer(timerValue);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Makes complete sense. Thank you so much for the help!